# Storing resources of each instance of class?

Tags: android, static, bitmap

I have a customview with a field(it's name is step) that set in constructor(really I pass it's values as parameter when I create an instance).Also I create some Bitmaps in constructor width of Bitmaps is correspond to that field(that comes from constructor).I know how to create Bitmaps,but I have to crate many instance of that class,so each instance has it's Bitmaps and so I will have many Bitmaps in run time that usually are same(if step field be same between classes).I thought that I can create a static class that store bitmaps,but as I said,it is possible that they be different.

Is there any way to decrease the number of Bitmaps that are created?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a `Map`, `HashMap` (or maybe `WeakHashMap`) in particular. The values would be the bitmaps and the keys would be the step values. Placing it in a static instance of a class is reasonable

Comment: @MichaelButscher Please add your comment as an answer,so I can accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a `Map`, `HashMap` (or maybe `WeakHashMap`) in particular. The values would be the bitmaps and the keys would be the step values. Placing it in a static instance of a class is reasonable.